# Angular location path for navbar, cant change color.

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Angular $location.path() to determine the path on my blog which then highlights, on the navbar, which path is being used. The highlighting works except I want to change the color of the highlighted text when the path is being used. In the CSS below I've tried using :hover and :active to make the color of the text change. When you hover over the path link in the navbar the color changes, but when you click it initally changes to the color I assigned using :active but then when you move the mouse it goes back to the default active color. Any thoughts? Thanks.

HTML - NAVBAR

```
<div ng-controller='NavbarCtrl'>
     <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id='navbar'>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a id='headerTitle' class="navbar-brand" ng-href="#/">Teewinot</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('#/portfolio')}"><a class='navSubHeadings' ng-href="#/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('#/philosophy')}"><a class='navSubHeadings' ng-href="#/philosophy">Philosophy</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('#/about')}"><a class='navSubHeadings' ng-href="#/about">About The Partners</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ active: isActive('#/teewinot-blog')}"><a class='navSubHeadings' ng-href="#/teewinot-blog">Blog</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CONTROLLER

```
angular.module('Teewinot').controller('NavbarCtrl', function($scope,    $location) {
  'use strict'

  $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
      return viewLocation === $location.path();
  };
});
```

CSS

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: red;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active {
  color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the hash `#` from your call to $scope.isActive.

```
isActive('#/portfolio')
```

Try changing those to

```
isActive('/portfolio')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying active class to `li`

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('#/portfolio')}">
```

So you should have a styling for the active class like this

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a
```

Your CSS line would be

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.active > a  {
  color: yellow;
}
```